# VS 2012 or Monodevelop doesnot breaks Execution on Unity exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, unityvs

I am using UnityVS 2012 debugger tool to debug my game. It stops execution successfully when it hits the break point anywhere in the script,

but it do not breaks on unhandled exceptions if found. It keeps running. For example, I got the following unhandled exception in unity editor while debugging, but it didn't returned to the Visual Studio by breaking.

**MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
Headquarter.FilterByTag (System.String Tag) (at C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project Final Version (Ver. 23 Intgrtd)/Assets/scripts/Headquarter.cs:349)
Headquarter.Pock (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 Production_Info, UnityEngine.GameObject Target_Headquarter) (at C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project Final Version (Ver. 23 Intgrtd)/Assets/scripts/Headquarter.cs:302)
UnitMenu.Update () (at C:/Users/user/Desktop/Project Final Version (Ver. 23 Intgrtd)/Assets/scripts/UnitMenu.cs:62)**

I have tried it with mono develop as well but didn't get anything.

Rapid help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: These exceptions are being handled internally by unity. If they were unhandled and your debugger didn't catch them, the program would terminate.

Comment: Thanks alot. I have got your point. You are logically correct.